# Ignoring files in MVC Bundles

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundling-and-minification

We are using feature flags (set in Web.Config) to toggle the visibility in the UI of certain features that aren't yet complete.  I'd also like my MVC bundles to NOT include the related JS files since they would just be useless files the client would have to download when the feature isn't enabled.

So far I've found `IgnoreList.Ignore` but I can't seem to get it to work.  This is basically what I'm doing:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    if (!appConfiguration.FeatureXEnabled)
    {
        //Skip these files if the Feature X is not enabled!
        //When this flag is removed, these lines can be deleted and the files will be included like normal
        bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("~/App/Organization/SomeCtrl.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
        bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("~/App/Filters/SomeFilter.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
    }

    var globalBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app-global").Include(
        "~/App/RootCtrl.js",
        "~/App/Directives/*.js",
        "~/App/Services/*.js",
        "~/App/Application.js"
    );
    bundles.Add(globalBundle);

    var appOrgBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app-org");
    appOrgBundle.Include(
        "~/App/Filters/*.js",
        "~/App/Organization/*.js"
    );

    bundles.Add(appOrgBundle);
}
```

With the above code, the files in the ignore list are still being included!  What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have fought the ignore list when using expressions as well.  A simple work around I have found is to implement an `IBundleOrderer` that will exclude the files I do not want, and apply some ordering to how the files get included.  Although this is not really its intended use, I find it fills the gap.

The `IBundleOrderer` gets access to the full list of files (expression expanded to what files it matched).

```cs
public class ApplicationOrderer : IBundleOrderer {
    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        if (!AppSettings.FeatureFlag_ServiceIntegrationsEnabled)
        {
            //Skip these files if the Service Integrations Feature is not enabled!
            //When this flag is removed, these lines can be deleted and the files will be included like normal
            var serviceIntegrationPathsToIgnore = new[]
            {
                "/App/ServiceIntegrations/IntegrationSettingsModel.js",
                "/App/ServiceIntegrations/IntegrationSettingsService.js",
                "/App/ServiceIntegrations/ServiceIntegrationsCtrl.js"
            };
            files = files.Where(x => !serviceIntegrationPathsToIgnore.Contains(x.VirtualFile.VirtualPath));
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

Example Usage:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
        var appBundle = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/app")
            .IncludeDirectory("~/App/", "*.js", true)
        appBundle.Orderer = new ApplicationOrderer();
        bundles.Add(appBundle);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that the bundling code only happens once - during the initialisation of the website. If you are switching the `appConfiguration.FeatureXEnabled` flag without restarting/republishing the website then your change will be ignored.

One solution would be to create 2 separate bundles and then use Razor to display the correct bundle reference in your HTML.

e.g.

```
@{if (appConfiguration.FeatureXEnabled){
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/bundles/bundle-large.js"></script>
}else{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/bundles/bundle-small.js"></script>
}
```

Comment: I think you might be right.  The flag value is in the `web.config` file, so it won't be switching dynamically.  How can I "restart/republish" locally?  I've already tried stopping IIS and restarting Visual Studio.  No change.  I'd rather not have to make different bundles if I don't have to.

Comment: I would have expected that stopping IIS and restarting VS would have been enough. Try deleting the websites binaries. Or maybe the problem lies elsewhere? Are you sure you're picking up the correct config value?

Comment: Yes, I've even stepped through the code in debug mode to ensure that those lines are being hit.  They are, but those scripts are still being included.

Comment: You could always write your own bundle. (It looks quite simple.) At least then you could control how the ignore list is processed. http://stevescodingblog.co.uk/asp-net-bundling-minification-and-convention/

Answer (score 1):

I upvoted Gent's answer above because it helped me accomplish what I wanted.

But then I expanded upon it and created a generic `IBundleOrderer` that uses lambdas to exclude whatever items you want to exclude very simply.

Note the excludes parameter is a `params` list so you are not limited to a single exclusion pattern.  This doesn't do any ordering, but it could be easily added with another parameter.

```
public class ExcludeItemsOrderer : IBundleOrderer
{
    private Func<BundleFile, bool>[] _excludes;

    public ExcludeItemsOrderer(params Func<BundleFile, bool>[] excludes)
    {
        _excludes = excludes;
    }

    public IEnumerable<BundleFile> OrderFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files)
    {
        if(_excludes == null || _excludes.Length == 0)
        {
            return files;
        }

        foreach(var exclude in _excludes)
        {
            var exclusions = files.Where(exclude);
            files = files.Except(exclusions);
        }

        return files;
    }
}
```

And then I created an extension method to simplify using it:

```
public static class BundleExtensions
{
    public static Bundle AsIsOrderExcluding(this Bundle bundle, params Func<BundleFile, bool>[] excludes)
    {
        bundle.Orderer = new ExcludeItemsOrderer(excludes);
        return bundle;
    }
}
```

So that it can be easily applied as you create your bundles, like this:

```
bundles.Add(
            new ScriptBundle("~/Bundles/App/js")
                .IncludeDirectory("~/App", "*.js", true)
                .AsIsOrderExcluding(bf => bf.VirtualFile.VirtualPath.IndexOf("/skip_me/") >= 0)
            );
```

Comment: Nice generic impl allows me to cut down on boilerplate bc I'm using this across multiple web projects. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try defining the ignore list as follows (using wildcards instead of relative paths):

```
   bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*/App/Organization/SomeCtrl.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
   bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore("*/App/Filters/SomeFilter.js", OptimizationMode.Always);
```

Answer (score 0):

`Bundles.IgnoreList.Ignore(pattern)` doesn't work like that. It compares just the `Name` part of files (i.e not the full (virtual)path ) with `pattern` in any bundle going to be returned.
For example you can ignore files starting with name `old_style` prefix. This filtering will be applied for files **under any folder**.

`public IEnumerable<BundleFile> FilterIgnoredFiles(BundleContext context, IEnumerable<BundleFile> files) {
            return files.Where(f => !ShouldIgnore(context, f.VirtualFile.Name));
}`

See:
https://aspnetoptimization.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Optimization/IgnoreList.cs